# YUM Command hangs when using root privilege

Tags: redhat, yum

I'm trying to execute yum command in redhat 7, when I use yum without root privilege it works fine but when I use root privilege (with sudo or with root user), it hangs and take a long time without any result.

I tried to see if there is any proccess (using top command) in the same time when the command hangs so I found that in the time of launching the command, a yum process appears and after that the command continue hanging and no processes appear.

I tried yum command with basic privilege:

```
$ yum list installed
```

Result: all installed packages

I tried yum command with root privilege:

```
$ sudo yum list installed
```

Result: hangs or freeze without any result

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, it ended up being storage at its 100%

you can confirm that by running `df -h` in my case i got the following:

```
Filesystem                           Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
...
/dev/mapper/sysvg-varlv              8.0G  8.0G   20K 100% /var
...
```

So i checked the /var folder with `du -sh /var` or `du -sh *` if you previously cd'd to it.

In my case i found some very huge files so since i needed to install my packages I moved those huge files to another location (can be your home directory), rebooted the server and once it was back I was able to finish my installations.

Note: you can sort the files by its size with `du -sh /path/to/files | sort -h`